# Why does IIS recycle my application pool every 15 minutes?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, iis, asp.net, application-pools

Today we have a huge number of users on our ASP.NET MVC IIS 7 web application.

I notice that approx. every 15 minutes, the application pool process is killed and a new one is started.

I did not find any specific reason for this. I could *imagine* that memory limits were hit but I found no way to verify this.

The application pool has the default settings.

**So my question is:**

- Can I read somewhere (Event Log?) why an application pool was recycled?

**Update 1**

This is the memory over time. It seems that when it runs to 12 GB (the server's physical memory), the process is being killed:

[image]

One assumption is also that for each user, the session for this user takes some bytes of RAM so when new user enter the system, the memory gets larger and larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question, yes, you can view application pool recycle events in the Windows System event log. Filter for event source 'WAS'.

By default only the following recycle reasons are logged;

- Private Memory Limit Exceeded
- Regular Time Interval
- Virtual Memory Limit Exceeded

You can change the defaults and enable logging for other recycle events in

`Application Pool | Advanced settings | Recycling | Generate Recycle Event Log Entry`

By default the application pool won't recycle for virtual memory limit or private memory limit (the default limit is set to 0 = never).